# JMS queue limit consumers

Tags: bpel

Oi
I've got two bpel processes. Process A puts message in a queue and Process B consumes the messages and does some work.
What I'm looking for is a way to limit the number of messages being handled at the same time. So limiting the number of Processes B running simultaneously.

adapter.jms.receive.threads - this parameter indicates the number of poller threads that are created when an adapter endpoint is activated. The default is 1. Each poller thread receives its own message that is processed independently and thus allows for increased throughput.

I think this parameter does what i'm looking for but I see no difference with it.

What i'm doing to test it is pushing a bunch of messages into the queue and immediately its created an execution instance no matter what value i have in adapter.jms.receive.threads.

Shouldn't this property limit the number of requests being handled simultaneously? Can you think of any reason for it not working? Am I missing any configuration? Any compability issue?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which exact version you are using but because you mentioned "adapter.jms.receive.threads" I assume you are at least on Oracle BPEL 11g+.

Described behaviour occurs if you don't override the default value of bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy property (which is set to "async.persist"). Changing bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy on your component to "sync" should solve your problem.

Precisely, add the following property to your component definition inside composite.xml file:

`<property name="bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy" type="xs:string" many="false">sync</property>`